# Error raised at top level: Fluent.EntityError.noDatabase

Tags: postgresql, vapor

I am trying to fix an error I have been getting recently when I run my Vapor project.

It builds fine, but when it runs, it crashes. Here is my log:

```
fatal error: Error raised at top level: Fluent.EntityError.noDatabase: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.58.6/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 184
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100fe7cc0 swift_reportError + 132
1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000101004f50 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalErrorInFile + 112
2    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100fb3370 partial apply for (_assertionFailed(StaticString, String, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never).(closure #1).(closure #1).(closure #1) + 99
3    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100dfb0a0 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 355
4    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100fb32b0 partial apply for (_assertionFailed(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never).(closure #1).(closure #1) + 144
5    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100dfb5b0 specialized specialized String._withUnsafeBufferPointerToUTF8<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) throws -> A) throws -> A + 124
6    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100f57af0 partial apply for (_assertionFailed(StaticString, String, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never).(closure #1) + 185
7    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100dfb0a0 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 355
8    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100dfae80 _assertionFailed(StaticString, String, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never + 144
9    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100e1e540 swift_unexpectedError_merged + 569
10   App                                0x0000000100001ef0 main + 2798
11   libdyld.dylib                      0x00007fff974375ac start + 1
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

I am using the VaporPostgreSQL package. Here is my `Package.swift`:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "mist",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 2),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/postgresql-provider.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1)
    ],
    exclude: [
        "Config",
        "Database",
        "Localization",
        "Public",
        "Resources",
        "Tests",
    ]
)
```

And `main.swift`:

```
import Vapor
import VaporPostgreSQL
import Auth
import HTTP

let drop = Droplet()
let auth = AuthMiddleware(user: User.self)

try drop.addProvider(VaporPostgreSQL.Provider.self)
drop.preparations.append(Post.self)
drop.preparations.append(User.self)
drop.preparations.append(Site.self)
drop.middleware.append(auth)

let admin = AdminController()
var site = Site(name: "", theme: "")

if let retreivedSite = try Site.all().first {
    site = retreivedSite
} else {
    drop.get { req in
        return Response(redirect: "http://localhost:8080/login")
    }
}

drop.get { req in
    return try drop.view.make("Themes/VaporDark/index", [
        "posts": Node(node: JSON(Post.all().makeNode()))
    ])
}

admin.addRoutes(to: drop)

drop.resource("posts", PostController())

drop.run()
```

My postgres version is 9.6.1

For some reason VaporPostgreSQL won't update and I think that might be part of the problem. I have tried `vapor xcode`, `vapor build` and `vapor clean`, but I can't get the latest version.

[image]

Comment: The error says noDatabase so could you post your secrets/postgresql.json configuration file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
if let retreivedSite = try Site.all().first {
    site = retreivedSite
} else {
    drop.get { req in
        return Response(redirect: "http://localhost:8080/login")
    }
}
```

More specifically, the `Site.all()` call. We don't prepare the models until the `run()` command is called, so, to look up `Site` before that point, the model will need to be prepared manually.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**A.**

You should verify the information in your secrets/postgresql.json

```
{
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "user": "username",
    "password": "",
    "database": "nameofyourdb",
    "port": 5432
}
```

Make sure the configuration information is correct. Try to manually connect to your postgresql instance from terminal and make sure that your db actually exists.

**B.**

Sometimes, data gets corrupted. Try to revert your database instance and run again your application. If you are using Xcode to run the project you can do this from Edit scheme / Run / Arguments :

[image]

```
prepare --revert
```

Notice the console will ask you if you are sure to perform the action, you will require to enter `Y` as acceptance. After that you will need to remove the argument above, next time you run your application it will have an fresh db.

*Warning: This action will remove all of your information so you should obviously be in a development environment or at least to have a backup of your information.*